# IIS Management Console has disappeared on my XP machine

Tags: windows-xp, iis

I have IIS up and running on an older Windows XP Professional; I can verify that services are present, running, and web works as expected.

However, in the management console (right click Computer, Manage), there's no node beneath "Services and Applications" for IIS.

Is there a quicker way for me to get it back than to start trying to reinstall IIS (which I really don't want to do).

I don't really need that node there, as long as I can get to the console. Is there a shortcut I can make that will open the relevant console instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registering inetmgr.dll works for me.

```
regsvr32 C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\inetmgr.dll
```

Or you can access to only IIS console

```
Controls Panel -> Administrators Tools -> IIS
```

Comment: And the administrator tools didn't have that console shortcut either, hence my question. It's an older machine that has "lived a bit" so no wonder there's some oddball problems with it.